# Creating custom loss function, error with unstacking tensor in tensorflow, python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

Creating a weighted gaussian loss function for use in deep learning models and getting the following error message when running model.fit for training data

> ValueError: Dimension must be 2 but is 1 for '{{node
> gaussian_loss/unstack_1}} = UnpackT=DT_FLOAT, axis=-1, num=2'
> with input shapes: [?,1].

attached below is the code for the function:

```
def w_g_l(weight_train, weight_test, train_num):
    def gaussian_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        if y_true.get_shape()[0] == train_num:
            weight=weight_train
        else:
            weight=weight_test
            
        mu, sigma = tf.unstack(y_pred, num=2, axis=-1)
        truevals, dummy = tf.unstack(y_true, num=2, axis=-1)
        
        mu = tf.expand_dims(mu, -1)
        sigma = tf.expand_dims(sigma, -1)
        truevals = tf.expand_dims(truevals, -1)
        
        nll = (
            tf.math.square(truevals-mu)/(2.0 * tf.math.square(sigma))
            + tf.math.log(sigma) + tf.math.log(weight)
        )
        
        return tf.math.reduce_mean(nll) - tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.log(weight))
    return gaussian_loss
```

Any clues? It seems to be an issue with the truevals, dummy = tf.unstack(y_pred, num=2, axis=-1) line, but I'm unsure what specifically can fix it.

Model is below:

```
def build_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([
        layers.Dense(units=2, input_dim=2, activation = 'relu'),
        layers.Dense(units=12, activation = 'relu'),
        layers.Dense(units=2, activation = 'softplus')
    ])
    my_loss = w_g_l(weight_train, weight_test, 1148)
    loss=my_loss

    model.compile(loss = loss, optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01), metrics = ['mse', my_loss])
    return model
```

Comment: So, where are the y_true values? What is their shape?

Comment: This is my issue, having taken this from third party code, I'm unsure as to where those true values are coming from, my vague thought was that this would be coming from the model, but I'm coming at this a bit blind in honesty

Comment: It's your data. It's coming from `fit`

Comment: so I need my model to be producing an estimate of y and the true values?

Comment: `y_pred` is the result of the model. `y_true` is "your data", the data you "gave to the model" in `fit`. The error is saying that "your data" does not have the shape necessary to divide in two tensors.

Comment: I see, so my y_true is essentially the y input, which should be 1148 x 1. The unstack doesn't work however, even when I set num to 1, I instead get:  ' Incompatible shapes: [1,32,1] vs. [493,1]',  Very unsure where the 1,32,1, and 493, 1 are coming from

Comment: please post the full code (as opposed to code parts) so that users can replicate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your loss function is expecting `y_true` (which is data coming from your `y_train` that you passed to `fit`) to have two elements in the last dimension for unstacking in `truevals` and `dummy`.

One solution is making `truevals = y_true`, since you don't seem to have dummy values in your data.

Another solution is adding dummy values to your data like:

```
dummy_data = numpy.zeros(y_train.shape)

if len(y_train.shape) == 1:
    y_train = numpy.stack([y_train, dummy_data], axis=-1)
else:
    y_train = numpy.concatenate([y_train, dummy_data], axis=-1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried these and both seem to give me an error as above, saying 'Incompatible shapes: [32,1] vs. [493,1]' although it isn't telling me which line this is at

Comment: It seems there is a problem with the weights. What are they? If you're using `fit`, you will never use both weights, you will use only one of them. They seem to compare the batch size to set the weights (which is weird). Do you know what these weights are? Should they be different in train and test?=